# How to ajax validate a form from formset in Django

Tags: django

Lets say I have page with a formset

```
class PageView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {'formset': self.get_formset()}
```

I would like to ajax validate the forms on each form being filled out.

```
class ValidateForm(FormView):
    def form_validate(self, form):
        return True
```

My problem is that in formset the field names are different to the normal form and my `ValidateForm` view will not able to validate formset data. Is there a easy way to transform?

Comment: Do you mean as submitting the whole form? or submitting each subform individually?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but you can use the `prefix` parameter when instantiating the form to give it the same field names it would have in a formset.

Comment: @petkostas yes I want to submit individual sub form via ajax

Comment: Is there a specific reason you would need to submit each form individually?

Comment: @petkostas we have a checkout page and would like to validate shipping address, billing address, credit card form step by step in the same page.

Comment: It would be easier to create individual forms for each specific part and validate them rather than using a formset, include the forms in context (get_context_data if you are using CBV's) assign the forms to specific FormViews and then submit them through ajax, formsets are going to be a pain with ajax, but in case you can't go with the above check django-extra-views it has CBV's for formsets, you can dig the source code and find the way to submit the formsets.

Comment: @petkostas thanks yeah we have decided that formset is in the too hard basket and let go of js fallback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah that would work I guess.